# Error adding a OLSR to ns2.35 undefined reference to `OLSR_pkt::offset_'

Tags: networking, network-protocols, ns2

I am trying to add the protocol olsr in ns2.35. I am getting this below error When i try to "make" ns2.

trace/cmu-trace.o: In function `CMUTrace::format_olsr(Packet*, int)':
cmu-trace.cc:(.text+0x1eb1): undefined reference to`OLSR_pkt::offset_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ns] Error 1

I added olsr protocol by following the steps given in the link http://elmurod.net/en/index.php/archives/157

Please help me to overcome this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

---

HOWTO ns-2.35 + olsr :

```
$ tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing

```
$ cd ns-allinone-2.35/
$ patch -p0 < umolsr-ns235_v1.0-2014.patch
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNeVZhWFVVZlJnUEU/view?usp=sharing

```
$ ./install
$ cd ns-2.35/
$ cp ns ns-olsr
$ sudo cp ns-olsr /usr/local/bin/
.... Then you can do $ ns-olsr ddebbie90-scenario.tcl
```

Simulaton examples : umolsr-examples-05.2016.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNWXlHRmxQV0hpWXM/view?usp=sharing

? Any issues ? Then please specify your OS :

```
1) $ uname -m
2) $ cat /etc/issue
```

---